# What sorts of objects can you target with the Enlarge/Reduce spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, objects

The [*enlarge/reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) spell has the following text specifying its target:

> You cause a creature or an object you can see within range to grow larger or smaller for the duration. Choose either a creature or **an object that is neither worn nor carried**. If the target is unwilling, it can make a Constitution saving throw. On a success, the spell has no effect.

I had always imagined this spell being used on swords, books, arrows, goblets, and other such objects, in addition to creatures. But it seems like this is not the case. However there are questions here on RPG.SE asking about such things and no one seems to call them out as invalid targets, since they can be carried:

- [If I cast the Enlarge/Reduce spell on an arrow, what weapon could it count as?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143385/if-i-cast-the-enlarge-reduce-spell-on-an-arrow-what-weapon-could-it-count-as)
- [Is it against RAW to allow an Enlarged/Oversized net to restrain a Huge creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111786/is-it-against-raw-to-allow-an-enlarged-oversized-net-to-restrain-a-huge-creature)
- [Can you conjure a small version of a vehicle with Minor Conjuration and use Enlarge/Reduce to grow it into a copy of the original vehicle?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148685/can-you-conjure-a-small-version-of-a-vehicle-with-minor-conjuration-and-use-enla)

So I have to wonder if I am missing something.

Can you enlarge these types of average inanimate objects that are normally carried? If not, what are the typical object targets of an *enlarge/reduce* spell?

Comment: Related: [What items are considered "worn or carried"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120716/48759)

Comment: Ooooooooh... Things that are not *currently* worn or carried... Thanks @linksassin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ... an object that is neither worn nor carried ...

... prevents you from casting the spell offensively on, say, the battleaxe or armor of the giant you are fighting. If you kill the giant, its battleaxe or armor are now valid targets of the spell (as is the dead giant).

What matters is not *if* the object can be worn or carried but if it is being worn or carried *right now*.

The size of the object is not relevant provided that it is a *single* object - a battleaxe or armor are single objects (probably), a castle or tavern aren't (probably) and a wagon might or might not be. Basically whether a thing is a single object (and a valid target) or a collection of objects (and isn't) is DMs call.